# cabal install yi dlopen() Error

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal-install

I'm trying to install the Yi-Editor via cabal on OSX 10.10.1. At first I got the `yi: can't load .so/.DLL for:` Error, which was fixed by `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib`. But now I get another Error thats not described in the FAQ:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             
  ( src/executable/Main.hs, dist/build/yi/yi-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/yi/yi ...
ld: couldn't dlopen() /usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib: 
dlopen(/usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib, 1): 
Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData 
for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install yi-0.11.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
yi-0.11.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

SOLVED!

Seems to be a problem with 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' set it to default and use 'DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH' instead.

Comment: Looks like it can't find some sqlite3 symbols, do you have sqlite3-dev installed and on your path?

Comment: I installed sqlite3 via macports, but couldn't find a -dev Version